# Operating on members of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers.

```
L1=[12,32,21,......]
```

I need to execute the following test on each member,tolerating upto 2 failures-no more.

NOTE : The function is ILLUSTRATIVE( not actual )- the objective is to test each member and return failed members as a list.
Also for performance sake,the idea is to abort as soon as failures exceed 2.

```
def isgreaterthan10(self,x):
    if x<10:
        return false
    else:
        return true
```

So I do the following.

```
def evaluateList(L1):
    Failedlist=list()
    Failures=0
    for x in L1:
        if not isgreaterthan10(x):
            Failedlist.add(x)
            Failures+=1
            if Failures>2:
                return (False,[])
    return (True,Failedlist)
```

But I am sure this can be done in a more efficient 'pythonic' way,as performance is premium.
Would appreciate any help in achieving the same.
I am on Python 2.6.5

Comment: There is no need to return a tuple consisting of a boolean and a list; empty lists evaluate as false in a boolean context, non-empty lists, true.

Comment: There is a need - as an empty list would not indicate whether there was an abort owing to exceeding 2 or that simply everything succeeded.

Comment: I believe what you have there is more efficient than using list comprehension, especially if the list is large (in the ten of thousands). List comprehension goes through all the items in the list, whereas your solution stops short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips to make it more Pythonic:

When naming things, functions use underscores, not CamelCase, and variables start with lowercase letters.

Your filter function can simply return the value of `x<10`, rather than branching and returning a Boolean constant. I'm assuming by the presence of `self` that it is part of a class, but since it never uses `self`, you can define it to be a static method instead.

```
@staticmethod
def is_greater_than_10(x):
    return x < 10
```

(If it's not part of a class, simply remove `self` from the argument list.)

In your evaluation function, there's no need to return an explicit Boolean constant to indicate success or failure (but not for the reason I initially posted in my comment). Instead, raise an exception to indicate too many small values.

```
class TooManySmallValues(Exception):
    pass

def evaluate_list(l1):
    failed_list = list()
    failures=0
    for x in l1:
        if not is_greater_than_10(x):
            failed_list.append(x)
            failures+=1
            if failures>2:
                raise TooManySmallValues()
    return failed_list
```

Now, where you might have called the function like this:

```
result, failures = evaluate_list(some_list)
if not result:
    # do something about the many small values
else:
    # do something about the acceptable list and the small number of failure
```

you would call it like this:

```
try:
    failures = evaluate_list(some_list)
except TooManySmallValues:
    # do something about the many small values
```

Finally, unless the list is huge and you will actually observe a significant performance gain by stopping early, use a list comprehension to generate all failures at once, then check how many there were:

```
def improved_evaluate_list(l1):
    failed_list = [ x for x in l1 if not is_greater_than_10(x) ]
    if len(failed_list) > 2:
        raise TooManySmallValues()
    else:
        return failed_list
```

Answer (score 3):

If performance is key, I'd vectorize it using numpy (or scipy).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> L1 = [47, 92, 65, 25, 44, 8, 74, 42, 48, 56, 74, 5, 60, 84, 88, 16, 69, 87, 9, 82, 69, 82, 40, 49, 1, 45, 93, 70, 22, 40, 97, 49, 95, 34, 28, 91, 79, 9, 32, 91, 41, 22, 36, 2, 57, 69, 81, 73, 7, 71]
>>> arr = numpy.array(L1)
>>> count_of_num_greater_than_10 = numpy.sum(arr > 10)
>>> num_greater_than_10 <= 2
False
```

Granted, it won't short-circuit, so if you have two false statements very early on, it will calculate the rest.

#### Timing results.

Simple timing test, doing a 1000 iterations with a random 1000 element list populated with numbers from 1 to 100 (with the setup of array creation done before starting the timer), shows the vectorized method is over 100 times faster.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('sum([n>10 for n in L1])>=2', 
      setup='import numpy; L1=list(numpy.random.randint(1,100,1000))', 
      number=1000)
2.539483070373535
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.sum(L1>10)>=2', 
      setup='import numpy; L1=numpy.random.randint(1,100,1000)', 
      number=1000)
0.01939105987548828
```

If you want failed members, its not that hard; you can find the numbers not greater than 10 with:

```
>>> list(arr[numpy.where(arr<10)])
[8, 5, 9, 1, 9, 2, 7]
```

Again the vectorized version is orders of magnitude faster than the non-vectorized version:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in L1 if i < 10]', 
      setup='import numpy; L1=list(numpy.random.randint(1,100,1000))', 
      number=1000)
0.4471170902252197
>>> timeit.timeit('L1[numpy.where(L1<10)]', 
      setup='import numpy; L1=numpy.random.randint(1,100,1000)', 
      number=1000)
0.011003971099853516
```

Comment: You should use `numpy.sum` eg. `(arr > 10).sum()`

Comment: @jamylak - Yes.  Silly mistake.  On my system: `timeit.timeit('sum(a)', setup='import random; import numpy; a=numpy.random.randint(1,100,10000)', number=1000)` gives 2.5 seconds, while `timeit.timeit('numpy.sum(a)', setup='import random; import numpy; a=numpy.random.randint(1,100,10000)', number=1000)` is only 0.014 seconds.  (~200 times faster).

Comment: +1 also I was expecting those sort of drastic timing differences

Answer (score 2):

The best way is through `numpy` (look at the timings by @drjimbob), but here is a pure python solution. Unlike the solutions that create a list comp, this solution evaluates lazily.

```
from operator import gt
from itertools import ifilter, islice
from functools import partial

def F(seq, N, limit):
    it = ifilter(partial(gt, limit), seq)
    failed = list(islice(it, N))
    return (True, failed) if next(it, None) is None else (False, [])

>>> F([10, 11, 12], 2, 10)
(True, [])
>>> F([1, 2], 2, 10)
(True, [1, 2])
>>> F([1, 2, 3], 2, 10)
(False, [])
```

However you will probably find that your solution runs faster anyway (not considering numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can simplify your first function. I'll leave out the `self` so it's easy to test, but modifying it into a class method is trivial:

```
def isgreaterthan10(x):
    return x > 10
```

Now, we can use a list comprehension to simplify the `evaluateList` function:

```
def evaluateList(li):
    x = [v for v in li if not is_greater(v)]
    if len(x) > 2:
        return (False, [])
    return (True, x)
```

Or if you're using python 3 and really want to play code golf:

```
def evaluate(li):
    x = [v for v in li if not is_greater(v)]
    return (True, []) if len(x) > 2 else (False, x)
```

Comment: @MarkRansom Oops, yeah, just saw that. Fixed (I think).

Comment: You missed the bug in `isgreaterthan10`.

Comment: Isn't the original solution more efficient?

Comment: I agree: the original solution is more efficient: it returns as soon as two failures are encountered. This solution goes through every items in the list (AKA list comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
>>> def evaluateList(thelist):
...     mylist = [i for i in thelist if i < 10]
...     return (len(mylist)<=2,mylist if len(mylist)<=2 else [])
>>> L = [4, 36, 34, 12, 43, 9, 16, 19]
>>> evaluateList(L)
(True, [4, 9])
>>> K = [1, 64, 23, 6, 23, 14, 16, 22, 8]
(False, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use filter():

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def isnotgreaterthan10(x):
    return x <= 10

def evaluateList(L1):
    l = filter(isnotgreaterthan10, L1)
    return False if len(l) > 1 else True

def main():
    my_list_bad = [1, 2, 14, 15, 17]
    my_list_good = [1, 19, 22, 23]

    if evaluateList(my_list_bad):
        print("my_list_bad passes.")
    else:
        print("my_list_bad fails.")

    if evaluateList(my_list_good):
        print("my_list_good passes.")
    else:
        print("my_list_good fails.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```